# CMake sets same variable two times?

Tags: cmake

I was investigating CMake file and found a strange lines

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(Project1)

set(SRC_FILES ${SRC_FILES} ./file1.cpp)
set(SRC_FILES ${SRC_FILES} ./file2.cpp) # sets the same variable

add_library(lib_name ${SRC_FILES})
```

Why do we set variable `SRC_FILES` two times? is it a bug?

I was checking value of the variable

```
message(SOURCES="${SRC_FILES}")
```

and it prints

> SOURCES="./file1.cpp./file2.cpp

Is it a valid CMake file?

Comment: ***Why do we set variable SRC_FILES two times?*** User preference. You could list all source files the first time.  ***is it a bug?*** No

Comment: After you have a target with `add_library(lib_name ${SRC_FILES})`  you could even add additional sources to the lib_name target with [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly find to reassign a variable in cmake. Note though you could (and imho should) use either

```
list(APPEND SRC_FILES ./file1.cpp ./file2.cpp)
```

or

```
set(SRC_FILES ./file1.cpp ./file2.cpp)
```

instead for easier readability/shorter logic.

Use the latter in case you expect the `SRC_FILES` variable to be empty prior to your logic. In 99% of the cases you won't be passing preexisting variable from the parent cmake dir, so usually the second one is the way to go. Otherwise you may end up with sources from other targets among the source files of your lib.

Answer (score 2):

The second "set" assigns `SRC_FILES` the combined value of `${SRC_FILES} ./file2.cpp`. So it effectively **appends** the variable. Thus, the final result is `SRC_FILES` containing both file1 and file2.

This is a completely valid CMake file. Of course in this concrete example, it would be simpler to just assign both together like this:

```
set(SRC_FILES
   ${SRC_FILES} # This can be dropped if SRC_FILES doesn't contain previous value
   ./file1.cpp
   ./file2.cpp
)
```

NOTE: In modern CMake, it is a more elegant way to use `list(APPEND <list> new_value)` like this:

```
list(APPEND SRC_FILES ./file2.cpp)
```

Comment: Since you bring up Modern CMake in your answer, you'll know why to [avoid custom variables in the arguments of project commands](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1#avoid-custom-variables-in-the-arguments-of-project-commands). The Modern CMake solution is to not have a variable `SRC_FILES` at all.

Comment: @Friedrich Thanks! That's an interesting and useful guide.

Answer (score 0):

Remember when you started coding and saw a line like this:

```
x = x + 1
```

What you found is CMake's take on this pattern.

CMake's [`set`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) command will create a list if called with more than two arguments.

So the first `set` creates a string variable `SRC_FILES` containing *nothing* (CMake evaluates unset variables to *nothing* by default) and `"./file1.cpp"` and the second `set` creates a list of strings from `SRC_FILES` content and `"./file2.cpp"`.

Other answers have pointed out other ways to set `SRC_FILES` to the same value. What they failed to make clear is that `SRC_FILES` is completely superfluous. It is even considered an anti-pattern in Modern CMake. See the item [Avoid custom variables in the arguments of project commands](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1#avoid-custom-variables-in-the-arguments-of-project-commands).

A side note: paths are relative to the current CMake file so no need for `./` either.

So the clean, readable and idiomatic code would be

```
add_library(library_name file1.cpp file2.cpp)
```

It says "create a library *library_name* from *file1.cpp* and *file2.cpp*" which is really all that needs to be said.