# How do set(var ${var} value) and set(var "${var}" value) work in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Try running the following:

```
message("foo: ${foo}")
set(foo ${foo} abc)
message("foo: ${foo}")
set(foo ${foo} def)
message("foo: ${foo}")
set(foo ${foo} ghi)
message("foo: ${foo}")
```

The output will be:

```
foo: 
foo: abc
foo: abc;def
foo: abc;def;ghi
```

And if you change it to quote the variable references in the `set` invocations like this:

```
message("foo: ${foo}")
set(foo "${foo}" abc)
message("foo: ${foo}")
set(foo "${foo}" def)
message("foo: ${foo}")
set(foo "${foo}" ghi)
message("foo: ${foo}")
```

You'll instead see this:

```
foo: 
foo: ;abc
foo: ;abc;def
foo: ;abc;def;ghi
```

How is this working / why is this happening in terms of the mechanics of CMake?

Comment: meta note: this Q&A is designed to be a canonical for questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280985/11107541). I chose to write a new question because that question already got answers and I missed the opportunity to generalize it into something more helpful to future readers.

Comment: The first variant - `set(var ${var} val)` - is old style of appending to a list (the modern and more verbose style is `list(APPEND var val)`). The second variant - `set(var "${var}" val)` - is useless in 99% cases (on input it interprets `var` as *string* but on output `var` becomes a *list*). Why do you ever want to describe these things? The [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280985/11107541) is about basics of CMake and many other languages, which are perfectly allow to assign a variable as many times as one wants.

Comment: If you want to describe quoting aspects, then [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/when-should-i-quote-cmake-variables) seems to be a better place for such description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've observed, `set(varname ${varname} value)` appends a value to a variable using a semicolon as a separator (which you). (Note that there's another way you can append to list variables: [`list(APPEND <list> [<element> ...])`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#append)).

To understand how this is working / why this is happening, you need to understand how variable referencing works, how lists work, how the `set` command works, and how command argument handling works.

#### Variable Referencing in CMake

The docs for variable referencing can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references). TL;DR is that if you reference a non-existant variable without passing [`--warn-uninitialized`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-warn-uninitialized), CMake will evaluate the reference to an empty string. That's why the first `message` call above prints "foo: ", and why the first call to `set(foo ${foo} abc)` (which references `foo` in the second argument) will not error (as long as you don't use `--warn-uninitialized`)

#### Lists in CMake

In CMake, lists are just strings where each entry of the list is separated by a semicolon character. semicolons can be [escaped](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#escape-sequences) with a backslash. You can find the full docs on lists [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#lists).

#### The `set` command in CMake

From the CMake docs for [the `set` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html):

> Signatures of this command that specify a `<value>...` placeholder expect zero or more arguments. Multiple arguments will be joined as a [semicolon-separated list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#cmake-language-lists) to form the actual variable value to be set.

One behaviour of `set` that I'm pretty sure is undocumented is that if you pass a single argument that looks like a list, it won't escape the semicolons in that list.

#### Command Argument Handling in CMake

The docs for command arguments can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#command-arguments).

From the section on quoted arguments:

> Quoted argument content consists of all text between opening and closing quotes. Both [Escape Sequences](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#escape-sequences) and Variable References are evaluated. A quoted argument is always given to the command invocation as exactly one argument.

From the section on unquoted arguments:

> Unquoted argument content consists of all text in a contiguous block of allowed or escaped characters. Both Escape Sequences and Variable References are evaluated. The resulting value is divided in the same way Lists divide into elements. Each non-empty element is given to the command invocation as an argument. Therefore an unquoted argument may be given to a command invocation as zero or more arguments.

#### Tying it all Together

When you use `set(foo ${foo} abc)` (unquoted argument),

- In the first call, `${foo}` is evaluated to an empty string, so it is not passed as an argument, but the string argument `abc` is not empty, so it's passed as the first value argument- thus, `foo` gets set to `abc`.
- In the second call, `${foo}` is evaluated to a regular string / a list with one element (`abc`), and that string / one element is passed as the first value argument, along with `def` as the second value argument. `set` joins the two value arguments with a semicolon and the resulting string is assigned to `foo`.
- In the third call, `${foo}` is evaluated to a list containing `abc` and `def`, which get passed as the first and second value argument, respectively. Then `ghi` as the third argument. `set` joins the three value arguments by with a semicolon and the resulting string is assigned to `foo`.

When you use `set(foo "${foo}" abc)` (quoted argument),

- In the first call, `"${foo}"` is evaluated to an empty string, but recall that "*A quoted argument is always given to the command invocation as exactly one argument.*", so that empty string gets passed as the first argument to the `set` invocation. The string argument `abc` is not empty, so it's passed as the second value argument.  `set` joins the two value arguments with a semicolon and the resulting string is assigned to `foo`. Thus, you get `;abc` (a list where the first value is an empty string).
- In the second call, `"${foo}"` is evaluated to `;abc`. It's a list, but since it got specified as a quoted argument, the entries of the list are not each passed as individual arguments and `;abc` is passed as the first value argument, along with `def` as the second value argument. The two value arguments are joined with a semicolon and the resulting string is assigned to `foo` (`;abc;foo`- a list with three elements).
- A similar thing happens as in the second call in the third call.